# How can I return more than one JSON element for each prediction from a toy machine learning API that I have built?

Tags: python, json

I have built a toy machine learning API which returns predictions as to whether or not guests aboard the Titanic are likely to have died or not based on their personal details (age, sex, price paid, class, etc.).

My script returns a JSON output as such:

```
return jsonify({'predictions': str(predictions)})
```

Is it possible, however, to return specific elements such as price paid, sex, age, etc. (or even the entire row details) along with the prediction?

At present, the output looks like this (predictions only, each `1`/`0` representing the prediction as to whether or not each observed passenger will survive):

```
{
    "predictions": "[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, ...]"
}
```

I have attempted a couple of solutions whereby I display each guest's `Sex` alongside the prediction (where `X` is a `pandas` DataFrame) like this:

```
return jsonify(
        {
            'predictions': str(X["Sex"], predictions)
        }
)
```

But receive an error:

```
TypeError: str() argument 2 must be str, not list
```

I then tried:

```
return jsonify(
        {
                'name': str(X["Sex"]),
                'predictions': str(predictions)
        }
)
```

But this returns first the list of `Sex` values and then the predictions (which is what I expected, but I wasn't certain). (Note that `True` represents `MALE`/`M` and `False` represents `FEMALE`/`F`.)

```
{
    "name": "0      False\n1       True\n2      False\n3       True\n4      False\n5       True\n6      False\n7       True\n8      False\n9      False\n10 ...",
    "predictions": "[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, ...]"
}
```

How can I achieve the result of presenting an output where other details are presented?  Something like this (where `M`/`F` represents `Sex` / a single additional feature):

```
{
    "predictions": "[M, 0, M, 0, M, 0, F, 1, F, 1, M, 0, M, 1, ...]"
}
```

I suspect that something like an array (or even tuple) within an array would be what is needed here (if so, how can I implement that?).

Perhaps like this:

```
{
    "predictions": "[[M, 0], [M, 0], [M, 0], [F, 1], [F, 1], [M, 0], [M, 1], ...]"
}
```

(For those who are curious, [the dataset in question is freely available from Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic/data).)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot return more than one json string. You would just use more data structure.

In order to compose a large infographic, it may make sense to simply pass the entire set of data along as well (so long as it doesn't contain anything too personal or secure, etc., if it does strip it out first server side).

```
return jsonify(
    {
            'data': X,
            'predictions': str(predictions)
    }
)
```

Then on your front end manipulate the connection between various data points and outcomes.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your dictionary for person attributes looks like this:
`X = {'Sex': ['M', 'F', 'M', 'M']`
And predictions are like so:
`predictions = [0, 0, 0, 1]`

Then we can zip together the two arrays, and for each iteration, we output them as a tuple into an array.
Example in Python:

`result = 
{
    'predictions': [(sex, predict) for sex, prediction in zip(X['Sex'], predictions)]
}`

Comment: Thank you, but I am still receiving an error here: `TypeError: Object of type function is not JSON serializable`.  Also, the data are actually passed in as a CSV file (remember - this is a toy API, although real requests can indeed be made), and the data themselves take the following structure: `{"Sex": ["M", "F", "M", "M"], "Age": [10, 33, 32, 48], "Class": [3, 1, 2, 1]}` and so on.

Comment: @MusTheDataGuy [this](https://pastebin.com/qXRxrHHQ) code worked for me. Let me know if this is what you were looking for. I am not familiar with jsonify.